# How I can find missing numbers in consecutive numbers?

Tags: r

I have a data as below

```
ID   x    y 
1    0    1 
2    0    1
3    0    2
4    0    2
5    1    4
6    10   7
7    10   7
```

Y variable ranges from 1 to 7 and we can find 3,5,6 are missing in Y variable. How I can find missing numbers in consecutive numbers ?

Comment: something like `setdiff(min(dd$y):max(dd$y), unique(dd$y))`?

Comment: @MrFlick: Technically you don't need the `unique` because there is already one included in `setdiff` but there may be cases where it is faster to use it before calling `setdiff`.

Comment: If one of the answers were helpful your upvoting and accepting one of them is appreciated!

Answer (score 10):

The simplest solution would be

```
> setdiff(1:7, df$y)
[1] 3 5 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the data frame you give.

```
id = rep(1:7)
x = c(0,0,0,0,1,10,10)
y = c(1,1,2,2,4,7,7)

df = data.frame(id,x,y)
```

This is the way to find missing values from 1 to 7 in df$y. Figuring out unique values in df$y, and checking there is not unique values of df$y in rep(1:7) which is consecutive numbers from 1 to 7.

```
rep(1:7)[!(rep(1:7) %in%  unique(df$y))]
[1] 3 5 6
```

Comment: `rep(1:7)` is identical to `(1:7)` or `sequence(7)`

Comment: @thelatemail, `rep(1:7)` is almost the same with `sequence(7)`, not quiet same with `(1:7)`.

Comment: `identical(rep(1:7),(1:7))` == `TRUE` and... `(1:7)[!((1:7) %in%  unique(df$y))]` gives the same result as your answer. `sequence(7)` is essentially just `seq_len(7)`, which generates `1,2,3...` of the specified length. All of the above give the same result, with the only exception that `rep` is for repeating values, which isn't needed in this context at all.

Comment: @thelatemail, Yes, you are right. i was confused. I thought in some case `rep(1:7)` works but (1:7) doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try below logic to find the missing value,

```
val <- 400
num <- c(0:49,51:100)
if(any(val == num)){
  cat(val, "is present in the data")
}else{
  cat(val, "is missing in the data")
}
```